# Generate numbers with 3 digits

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer

I wanted to generate numbers starting from 000 to 120 in sequence.
I know you can generate numbers from 0 to 120 by using a loop.But I want all the numbers to have 3 digits.

The output should be

```
000
001
002 
...
...
120
```

Instead of

```
0
1
2
...
...
120
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this in python or should I be making separate code for `0-9` `10-99` and `100-120` ?

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: Codes are usually strings. You can't have a decimal like 001, it will be considered an octal.

Comment: Just in case: `print("{:03}".format(x))`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
["{0:03}".format(i) for i in range(121)]
```

or

```
["%03d" % i for i in range(121)]
```

To print:

```
print "\n".join(<either of the above expressions>)
```

More terse in Python 3.6+:

```
[f"{i:03}" for i in range(121)]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the syntax for more details? {:03} seems to work as well

Comment: `{:03}` will work for `format()` function. `f` string is more compact. Please see here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 4):

python 3.6

```
for i in range(121):
    print(f'{i:03}')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print [format(item, "03d") for item in xrange(121)]
```