# How to range numbers based on two number in python

Tags: python

I wanted to generate numbers starting from 0 to 111111111111 in sequence and the number list i want only `1` and `0` like this in order not randomly:-

```
0
01
10
11
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
etc..
```

and this [How to generate numbers based on a pattern in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652814/how-to-generate-numbers-based-on-a-pattern-in-python) does not have the right answer

Comment: What's the logic? Why do you have both `01` and `001`, but you don't have `010`?

Comment: do you want these as integers? `01` or `001` and so on is not a valid integer literal

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: no, i want to be string but that i can deal with here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22215011 @python_user

Comment: i forget to put `010` tbh @Barmar

Comment: @K.JohnMichel can you explain the logic as asked in the earlier comment?

Comment: Why do you have `01` and `001` but not `1`?

Comment: It looks like the pattern is 0 + `range(1, 2**n) for n in range(2, 13)`. But why exclude 1? [My previous comment had two off-by-one errors, so I deleted it.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting as an answer based on my understanding, might be wrong.

```
from itertools import product

def pattern(order):
    yield '0'
    for i in range(1, order):
        yield from (''.join(map(str, j)) for j in product(range(2), repeat=i+1) if sum(j))

for i in pattern(3):
    print(i)
```

Output

```
0
01
10
11
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: No it's not, it is the right answer i want, thank you.

Comment: @K.JohnMichel if you can explain the logic it will benefit future readers of this question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to print every digit in a 12-bit integer, so we can print the number as a binary literal with 12-bits padded with 0's:

```py
for i in range(2 ** 12):
    print(f"{i:#012b}"[2:]) # strip "0b" prefix
```

Comment: it starts with `0000000000` not `0`, i want to start from `0`

Comment: @K.JohnMichel You still haven't explained why some numbers are included twice.

Comment: because i want to decrypt a ciphertext that have a secret key only 0 and 1 and the length maybe between 1 to 12 @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to get all 2-bit numbers then all 3-bit numbers and so on... (will it be 1 in the beginning, or the 0 is correct? I have assumed 0 is correct)

You can do it like:

```
last_no = 0b111111111111 # or (2 ** 12) - 1
i = 2

print(0)
while 2 ** i < last_no:
    for j in range(1, 2 ** i):
        print(f"{j:#0{i + 2}b}"[2:])
    i += 1
else:
    for j in range(1, last_no + 1):
        print(f"{j:#0{i + 2}b}"[2:])
```

output:

```
0
01
10
11
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
0001
0010
0011
...and so on
```